# Imagemagick cannot be installed on windows server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, imagemagick

here is my ruby version:

```
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x64-mingw32]
```

I have a peculiar problem, here is what I am trying:
    gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib="c:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.7-Q8\lib" --with-opt-include="c:\Program Files (x8
        6)\ImageMagick-6.7.7-Q8\include" --with-opt-dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.7-Q8"

I have installed ImageMagick exe file without problem in c:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.7-Q8

when I want to install with gems, I get error:

```
extconf.rb failed
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You ma
need configuration options.
```

Then I go and check the mkmf.log, here I see that it cannot read the library:

```
have_library: checking for main() in -lCORE_RL_magick_... -------------------- no
```

I am going to the lib directory of Imagemagick and here is what I have:

```
CORE_RL_magick_.lib
CORE_RL_Magick++_.lib
CORE_RL_wand_.lib
X11.lib
```

does it mean one of my lib libraries are missing or does it mean it cannot read them? I am totally frustrated.

this also does not work for me:

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_install_rmagick_gem_on_Windows

Answer (score 0):

I cannot believe how ridiculously I solved the problem,

1-I uninstalled the ruby and installed an older version:

```
ruby 2.1.7p400 (2015-08-18 revision 51632) [x64-mingw32]
```

2-I uninstalled the imagemagic.exe and installed a different version of Imagemagick from its website:
[Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)

```
ImageMagick-6.9.3-0-Q16-x64-dll.exe
```

3- I removed the redmine where I wanted to have `imagemagick` completely , I downloaded redmine again, I don't even remember different redmine or not,and I extracted again, to be safe to remove whatever installations I did in the past.

I ran the: `bundle install`

and the imagemagick now had been installed successfully.